# Where to insert data after sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

> 1. Actual database in localhost:30000 ------------- I used this as Shard1
> 2. another mongod  in localhost:30001 ------------- Shard2
> 3. another mongod  in localhost:30002 ------------- Shard3

Added 1 config server and Router pointing the configdb

Now in Router,

```
1. mongo admin
2. sh.addShard("localhost:30000")..30002           //Added 3 shards successfully
3. sh.enableSharding("myDatabasename in shard1")  //Enabled successfully
4. sh.shardCollection(...)                       //Shard Collection successfully
```

I checked each shards and I am able to see that it is split-ed in ascending order like

```
shard key starting with A-D in shard2 as chunk 1
shard key starting with E-H in shard3 as chunk 1
shard key starting with I-O in shard1 as chunk 1
shard key starting with P in shard1 as chunk 2               //had upto P only
```

*Now I need to insert a new record means in which mongo instance I have to insert?*

I tried in `shard1` and inserted a new record with sharding key starting with E, which is getting inserted in `shard1` itself whereas it has to be inserted in `shard3`.

Answer (score 1):

With a sharded cluster, you need to insert data via a `mongos` process. A `mongos` process acts as a query router: it directs queries/updates to the appropriate shard(s) based on the current cluster configuration and metadata.  Typically you deploy one `mongos` per application server.

From your driver point of view, you can update your connect string and replace the address of your standalone server or replica set seed lists with one or more mongos servers to use.

For more information, you're best starting with the [Sharding Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this but I'm getting an error like `error preparing documents for insert :: caused by :: tried to insert object with
 no valid shard key for { aff: 1.0 } : { _id: ObjectId('52b28a305bbcf6ab`

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: what is your shard key for this collection?  It sounds like you may be trying to insert a document that is missing the required fields for the shard key.

Comment: `aff` is my shard key.  in this collection `db.Col.insert({....., "aff": "Ell, SA",...})` and the above is the error I got.  This is how I set shard collection `sh.shardCollection("db.Col", {aff: 1})`

Comment: That is a big collection and therefore I used `...`.  Please share your thoughts I'm struggling a lot in learning sharding.

Comment: What kind of field is "aff"? Only text, right? Remember that a shard key cannot be an array, nor a value of an array.